# Update column from column from another table partially matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables, the first table is called `IM_ITEM` and has the following columns

| ITEM_NO | DESCR | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | Orin Swift Black | " " |
| 10001 | Gold Peak Sweet tea | " " |
| 10002 | Vara Red Blend | " " |
| 10003 | Gatorade Lemon Lime | Gatorade |

The second table is a lookup table called `IM_ATTR_COD` and has the following columns

| ATTR_5 | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Orin Swift | Orin Swift |
| Gold Peak | Gold Peak |
| Vara | Vara |
| Gatorade | Gatorade |
| Comfort | Southern Comfort |

I want to update the empty field "BRAND" in table "IM_ITEM" by data from column "ATTR_5" in table "IM_ATTR_COD". When ATTR_5 partially matches data in "DESCR" from table IM_ITEM

I used the following code, but it did not work properly

```
UPDATE IM_ITEM
SET BRAND = ATTR_5
FROM IM_ITEM M
RIGHT JOIN IM_ATTR_COD R ON M.BRAND = R.ATTR_5
WHERE CHARINDEX (R.ATTR_5, M.DESCR) > 0
```

**Expected Result**

| ITEM_NO | DESCR | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | Orin Swift Black | Orin Swift |
| 10001 | Gold Peak Sweet tea | Gold Peak |
| 10002 | Vara Red Blend | Vara |
| 10003 | Gatorade Lemon Lime | Gatorade |

Any help, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LIKE clause and use the same in JOIN, as given below.

```sql
DECLARE @im_item table (ITEM_NO int, DESCR  varchar(500), BRAND varchar(50))
DECLARE @im_attr_cod table (attr_5 varchar(100), DESCR  varchar(500))
INSERT INTO @im_item 
values
(10000,'Orin Swift Black',  null)
,(10001,'Gold Peak Sweet tea',null);
INSERT INTO @im_attr_cod
values 
('Orin Swift',  'Orin Swift')
,('Gold Peak',  'Gold Peak');
UPDATE i 
SET BRAND = a.DESCR
FROM @im_item AS i
INNER JOIN @im_attr_cod as a
on i.DESCR like a.attr_5 + '%';
SELECT * FROM @im_item
```

| ITEM_NO | DESCR | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | Orin Swift Black | Orin Swift |
| 10001 | Gold Peak Sweet tea | Gold Peak |

Answer (score 0):

Without concat then:

```
UPDATE m
SET m.BRAND = r.ATTR_5
FROM IM_ITEM m
JOIN IM_ATTR_COD r
    ON m.DESCR LIKE r.ATTR_5 + '%'
WHERE ISNULL(m.BRAND,'') = ''
```

Comment: CONCAT is not recognized built-in function by sql also Brand should not stay null, I just showed it null because I want to fill it with the value from the other table

Comment: I updated my answer not to utilize concat - where statement is correct for your use though - ISNULL is to replace NULL with empty string just ins case that your column contains both

Comment: It updates it with only the first two letters matching words from the DESCR field. It did not update as the full matching value of ATTR_5. Is any way to fix that please?

Comment: Could you provide expected result?

Comment: **Expected Result**  
ITEM_NO, DESCR, BRAND
10000, Orin Swift Black,Orin Swift
10001,Gold Peak Sweet tea, Gold Peak
10002, Vara Red Blend, Vara
10003, Gatorade Lemon Lime, Gatorade

Comment: @BahaaGerges My answer produces EXACTLY the same result set , are you sure you typed/copied it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
UPDATE IM_ITEM
SET BRAND = ATTR_5
FROM IM_ITEM M
INNER JOIN IM_ATTR_COD R ON M.DESCR LIKE '%' + R.ATTR_5 + '%'
WHERE (M.BRAND = '' OR M.BRAND IS NULL)
```

In case you want it to apply to all rows, just remove `WHERE (M.BRAND = '' OR M.BRAND IS NULL)`

Comment: It update it with a totally different world than the one machining from ATTR_5? Is any way to fix that, please?